# How to add html in autocomplete ace editor?

Tags: autocomplete, ace-editor

Somebody can help me how to custom autocomplete for ace editor?
I need to display the `emoji images` such as below:

[image: emoji]

This editor is work well for me, but i need to insert the emoji images to the result of autocomplete.

```
var editor = ace.edit('editor');
editor.setTheme('ace/theme/github');
editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/markdown');
editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity; //prevents ace from logging annoying warnings
editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
    draceditor.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
});
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});

// Ace autocomplete
var emojiWordCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var wordList = emojis; // list emojis from `atwho/emojis.min.js`
        var obj = editor.getSession().getTokenAt(pos.row, pos.column.count);
        var curTokens = obj.value.split(/\s+/);
        var lastToken = curTokens[curTokens.length-1];

        if (lastToken[0] == ':') {
          console.log(lastToken);
          callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
              return {
                  caption: word,
                  value: word.replace(':', '') + ' ',
                  meta: 'emoji' // this should return as text only.
              };
          }));
        }
    }
}
editor.completers = [emojiWordCompleter]
```

my bad idea, i try with this `meta: '<img src="/path/to/emoji.png">'`, but of course it can't be work.

Any idea how to solve this? Thank so much before..

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to do this.
You can create a custom renderer similar to https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.language.core/blob/bfb5dd2acc/completedp.js#L44, or modify https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/autocomplete/popup.js and create pull request to ace.